# Stop panning on boundaries

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

My line chart is same code like this

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254

I have rect to listen zoom event but now I wanted to stop panning when we try to go where no data exists...like this  example

http://computationallyendowed.com/blog/2013/01/21/bounded-panning-in-d3.html

I have tried this login but i get 0 ,0  every time

Here is my code

```
function zoomedChart() {
    var _xDoamin =  x.domain();
    // console.log(_originalData)

    var t = zoomChart.translate(),
          tx = t[0],
          ty = t[1];
       console.log(tx,ty);
       console.log(svg.select("g.dataGroup"))
      // tx = Math.min(tx, 0);
      // tx = Math.max(tx, width);
      // zoomChart.translate([tx, ty]);

    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

    drawLines();
}       


  svg.append("rect").attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height).attr("class", "dummy")
          .call(zoomChart);
```